# Calculate a resale price to include the buy and sale % fee to break even. - avoiding circular reference

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, percentages

Hi i am not very good with math and i struggle to wrap my head around the formula needed to solve my problem. This is what i am trying to accomplish:

I see an item at a store for \$50 and there is a .5% buy fee. I buy the item and pay $50.25 total. I then decide i would rather have my money back and must resell the item. I now need to choose a resale price that will get me my \$50.25 plus cover the additional .5% sales fee. I will need to leave with my exact starting money. A \$0 profit or loss.

The problem is that every time i try to calculate the new resale price the sales fee goes up and now i must increase my sales price to compensate. I believe this is called a circular reference and can be avoided solving the problem algebraically.

Edit: fixed wording

Comment: Did you spend \$50 or \$50.25 at the beginning? And if you spent \$50.25 do you need the full amount back or only \$50?

Comment: Also if you decide the resale price to be $\$50.25$ then collect 0.5% on that from the buyer. If you keep increasing the resale price based on sales fee and in return increase the sales fee, then it will never end.

Comment: @Andrei \$50.25 is what it cost me to buy the item. \$50 is the advertised price in the store. For you second question the amount would be \$50.25. Sorry for the confusion i was carrying the fee over as a negative amount in my head thus i said \$50 beginning and end. Maybe i should have worded my question as such. Buy an item and resell it with \$0 profit/loss where there is a .5% buy and sell fee.

Comment: @MathLover That is my reason for this question. I have googled and came across similar situations and the usual two winning solutions are either limit the iterations in a circular reference or solve the problem algebraically. I assumed there was an end to this but it was so far out that using a circular reference would be inefficient. If there is no end then i just have to solve until i have a satisfactory margin of loss/profit?

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe the problem, both the seller and the buyer pay 5% of the advertised fee. So when you sell you get back only 95% of the advertised price. That means that you want to advertise at a price $P$, such that $$\frac{95}{100}P=50.25$$
or $$P=\frac{5025}{95}$$